# show relations between polygons by highlighting polygons

Tags: qgis, flow-map, spatial-relationship

Is it possible to show relations (for example traffic flow) between polygons (for example counties) by highlighting related polygons by doing a query on a start polygon using QGIS?

Here is an example: Blue polygons represent counties, delaunay-lines with arrow show traffic flow in one direction and (purple) desire-lines without arrow show total traffic flow.

What im doing so far: Flow lines or delaunay lines (created by aequilibrae plugin for qgis)

[image: currently: flowlines and delaunaylines]

What would be nice to have:
[image: wish: highlighted single relations]

To explain the second picture: You do a query on the green polygon. The result is that related polygons get highlighted by the amount of traffic relations (red for a lot, yellow for not so much, blue for no traffic at all) to the green polygon.

Comment: How do you manage the information about relations between polygons? I suppose you have some n:m relationship with attributes, eg traffic amount. So step 1 will be to select related polygons, and step 2 to draw the selected  polygons color coded according some attribute, and lines between polgygon centroids. I would use memory layers for this.

Comment: Relations are stored in a table and a matrix as csv. Each relation has information about traffic flow and two id's: one of start polygon and one of end polygon. So they can be linked by these id's. Can you explain how you would do this with memory layer?

Comment: I have no idea about highlighting yet, but memory layers was something I saw for the first time in the answer for this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283995/how-to-make-an-arrow-from-a-polygon-centroid-to-a-point, which is not so far from yours. I think you will need more items in the `SELECT` part than the `make_line` of that answer. You could post same data to play with. It would be nice to see a practical implementation of it.