# Making arrow from polygon centroid to point using QGIS

Tags: qgis, sqlite, swmm

I would like to present in QGIS a graphical information I have in two vector layers, an arrow. One layer has catchemnt areas as polygons and the other has the outlet points. The catchment areas layer has the ID of the outlet points in its Atribute Tables. The question is how to present an arrow rom the centroid to the point.

The background of the question is the SWMM model. In the picture below the yellow area points to node J3 and I want to draw that line.

[image]

In my case I have a subcatchment layer ('CatchmentAreas') with an attribute table like this:

```
fid Name    RainGage    Outlet
1   Sub_01  Rainfall    43 
2   Sub_02  Rainfall    38
3   Sub_03  Rainfall    73
```

and a outlet layer ('Junctions') like this:

```
id  DESC    INV_ELEV    
43  desc1   3.96
73  desc2   3.77
38  desc3   3.75
```

`Outlet` matches `id`

Comment: Is your question _"how to **automatically** make an arrow from **all** my polygon centroïd to **all** my outlet points"_ ?

Comment: I am not sure if "automatically" is the right word, but certainly I meant for ***all*** pairs. I do not know is it better with a set of instructions, a plug-in or a a virtual layer based on a SQL query, but it should be fast becuase it is just an auxiliary information I want for ***all*** pairs

Comment: but are you able to build the "logic" linking the polygon centroids to the outlet points ? (and to prepare the table for that ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a virtual layer to automatically create such a line, then you can style it as an arrow.

The following example assume the polygon layer is named `CatchmentAreas`, the point layer is called `Junctions` and the outlet ID column is called `Outlet` in `CatchmentAreas` and `id` in `Junctions`.

Go to the `layer` menu, `edit layer / add-edit virtual layer` and paste the new layer definition:

```sql
select make_line(st_centroid(CatchmentAreas.geometry),Junctions.geometry)
from CatchmentAreas, Junctions
where CatchmentAreas.Outlet = Junctions.id
```

This code joins the two layers based on the point ID, then it computes the centroid of the polygon and at last it builds a line between the centroid and the matching point.

Then you can style the new layer so it displays arrows
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to prepare an **origin-destination table** with all the start points and endpoints of the arrows you have to create.

Then you have some plug-in able to generate the line based on this origin-destination table.