# Showing Arrow connection relation between Polygon centroids to points in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, point

I am looking for a similar solution to [Making arrow from polygon centroid to point using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283995) but using ArcGIS Desktop.

I have a polygon and a point shapefile. The polygon area drains to the point node (This is a drainage node). The connectivity is coded in the attribute table name field in shapefile.

Now, I want to visually represent this connectivity using arrows from polygon to point. I also want this arrow indicator to be dynamic.

Meaning, any change in the attribute table reference will update the arrow connectivity. All these features are already available in QGIS. I want to replicate the same mechanism in ArcGIS Desktop.

[image: Shapefile attribute table structure and desired Arrow connectivity drawn]

Comment: What do you mean by "the attribute table reference"?

Comment: I mean, Any time I change the Polygon's connectivity node/ point in the 'Name' field at attribute table (of the polygon shape), the arrow will change from old node/ point to new one.

Comment: I do not know of any dynamic display of geometry features based on a relation. You could do it with a python script that would refresh a featureclass. If you had editor tracking enabled the script could just replace the edited values. Forget shapefiles, they don't have tracking. You should be using a filegeodatabase anyway.