# Selecting or highlighting upstream elements

Tags: qgis, hydrology, flow-map

I would like to use the information from the Swedish SMHI related with their hydrological model elements (catchment areas) that have a *Containment hierarchy* structure, each element has the information about its dowstream element, to select or highlight a whole catchment area like in the picture below:
[image]

The first step is to select them, but once that is done, of course there are other question.

Each element, among other data, has `AROID` (the ID of the element) and `OMRID_NED` (the ID of the element downstream).

I would like to do this in QGIS in a simple way, like a click in one element.

- The data I want to use is here: 
  [Delavrinningsområden SVAR_2016_3 (71,0 MB, zip)](https://www.smhi.se/polopoly_fs/1.126764!/avrinningsomraden_aro_y_2016_3.zip)
- An example of how they make it to work on their webpage is here [SMHI vattenwebb Modelldata per område](http://vattenweb.smhi.se/modelarea/)

Comment: I think I might be wrong about  *Containment hierarchy* because in this case one lement can be a subset of itself. If someone find the right definition, please ammend it.

Comment: I have just found a similar question, also without answer, but that seems similar to mine: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263008/show-relations-between-polygons-by-highlighting-polygons. A difference is that I would like to look recursively upstrem, so everything is highlighed not only the elements inmediately upstream.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the data, my best guess would be you need to select by the Name e.g. 'Mynnar i Höje å' (a catchment I recognise). One would expect to see a common ID number somewhere but it appers they just use the name.